# Captcha with WatiN Library

Tags: watin, captcha

Does anyone have experiance with **Captcha** on "**WatiN**" library ?

The site I want to get data is having a "captcha" on the login page. I can enter that value if app can show captcha image and wait for my input in a given text box on app.

Can we achive that from this library, if you can like to have a sample.

Answer (score 1):

ok...It seems you want to enter only captcha value manually..!!!other fields you want to automate.Ok the below solution may not be perfect but it works and its just an idea...or you can ask user to input the captcha value in an input box(use in place of msgbox),then take the value and put it in the captcha field.

```
        IE ie=new IE();

        ie.GoTo("http://captchas.net/registration/");
        ie.TextField(Find.ByName("user")).Value="username";
        ie.TextField(Find.ByName("mail")).Value="abcd@xyz.com";
        //string captch_value="";

        do
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Captcha value...after entering correct captcha press Ok");

           //captch_value=ie.Eval("window.prompt('enter captcha')");
        }while(ie.ContainsText("Wrong Password entered. Try again"));

        //ie.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).Value=captch_value;

        ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Submit")).Click();
```

Comment: But I am not going to show IE, So how the user see the Capcha image to enter test on it... I need to get that into a picture box on my form. Anyway of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Watin with a captcha solving service that has an API such as http://www.deathbycaptcha.com or similar site. So you would do the following.

1. Load the Page in Watin
2. Get the Captcha image
3. Submit it to the Captcha Solver API they will provide you with the results
4. Take that result and put it in the Captcha textbox.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know we can't automate all CAPTCHA's."Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart",As the name implies it is used to prevent automation.If we can automate whats the use of CAPTCHA?Only Poorly designed CAPTCHA's can be captured using complex matching algorithms.

Comment: Dear Suddu, 

I think you have mis-understood/not read carefully. I donw want to automate "CAPTCHA", I does need to show it to user and let the user to type that on a provided text box, and we need to wait for user input"... And we can proceed to next .. .